# An ellipse with focal points further and further...

Tags: conic-sections

Let's start with a definition of an ellipse that states: An ellipse is a set of points where each point's sum of distances from two focal points is equal to a constant value.

Now, we have got a two focal points and a given constant that creates an ellipse. Then we make those focal points further and further away. In my understanding the ellipse will become more and more "flat".

I have got two questions:

- How an eccentricity of the ellipse changes?
- If we reach a point where focal points are separated with a distance equal to the constant, does it mean our ellipse "degenerates" into a line? Or maybe a point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eccentricity is a measure of how much an ellipse has been "squished" from a circle.  A circle has not been squished from itself at all, so its eccentricity is 0.  A circle that has been completely squished becomes a line, which has an eccentricity of 1.  You can play around with it here: https://www.mathopenref.com/ellipseeccentricity.html  The answer to your second question is yes (it degenerates into a line).

Comment: Also the constant value is the length of the ellipse's major axis, as shown on the bottom of this animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLjnTgXXgXk

Answer (score 0):

I remember that for a conic with a focus at the origin, if the directrix is $x=\pm p$
where $p$ is a positive real number, and the eccentricity is a positive real number
$e$, the conic has a polar equation

$$r=\frac{ep}{1\pm e \cos \theta}$$
and when $e=1$ we not have a stright line but a parabola.